# how to clear h:inputtext in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am new to java server faces. When I click on submit button values are passed to bean method and `inputText` field need to be cleared. But here empty values or passed because java script code executes first. How do I send those values and then clear the `inputText` field?

Here is my code.

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelets </title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body >

        <h:form id="formdata" > 

            <b>FirstName </b> <h:inputText id="fname" value="#{hello.fname}"/><br/><br/>
            <b>LastName </b>  <h:inputText id="lname" value="#{hello.lname}"/> <br/> <br/>        
             <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{hello.setStudentName()}"  onclick="submitForm()"/>
             <h:commandButton id="viewall" value="View All" action="display"  />
        </h:form> 

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
            function submitForm()
            {
                var frm = document.getElementsByName('formdata')[0];
                frm.reset();  // Reset
             }
        </script>

    </h:body>
```

Hello.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="hello")
@SessionScoped

public class Hello {

     String fname="";
     String lname="";


     ArrayList studentList=new ArrayList();

    public void setFname(String f) {
        fname=f;
    }

    public void setLname(String l) {
        lname=l;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

     public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setStudentName(){
       Student s=new Student(fname,lname);
       studentList.add(s);
    }

    public ArrayList getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }  
    public void setStudentList(){}   
}
```

`index.xhtml` takes the input values and assigned to bean(Hello.java).
Suggest me a way where I can submit values when submit clicked and clear the `inputtext` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean in the jsf bean:

```
 public void setStudentName(){
   Student s=new Student(fname,lname);
   studentList.add(s);
   fname = "";
   lname="";
}
```